# Golbal variable type error in d3.js. How to solve it?

Tags: d3.js

Json data:

```
[{"specialty":"Anesthesiology","median":276000 },
{"specialty":"Cardiology: Electrophysiology","median":359622 },
{"specialty":"Cardiology: Inv-Intvl","median":400000 },
{"specialty":"Cardiology: Noninvasive","median":256250 },
{"specialty":"Dermatology","median":358750 }]
```

Type1: this code works.

```
d3.json("income.json", function(d){
   d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(d).enter().append("p").text("123");
});
```

Type2: but this code doesn't work. the error info is "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**"

```
var mydata;
d3.json("income.json", function(d){mydata = d;});
d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(mydata).enter().append("p").text("123");
```

Comment: Excuse me. I can't find the previous question by definitive key words, because I had no idea about why the code didn't work . I just knew the key word "synchronize" in this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the following call is running asynchronously and is not done parsing the data by the time you are trying to use it. Thus your variable 'mydata' is undefined.

```
d3.json("income.json", function(d){mydata = d;});
```

You should use 'Type 1' because it places the assignment into the callback of the d3.json function and populates your data once it is available

Hope this helps.